# Checking a string for a char and writing that char in the appropriate position in textbox

Tags: vb.net

Basically I'm trying to make a game, "Guess the person", in vb.net. I have two strings `FirstName` and `LastName` which hold the obvious data. I have two textboxes which contain a "_".

There are 5 buttons with a random letter as text on them. What is supposed to happen is, when you click a button it should check if the letter that is on the button is contained in either `FirstName` or `LastName`, and if it is, replace the appropriate underscore or underscores if there are more than one with the letter that is on that button. I was thinking of doing the check with

```
Dim letter As Char
FirstName.Contains(letter)
```

But I have no idea what to do next, how to see the position of that character or how to overwrite the appropriate underscore or to check if the letter appears more than one time.

Comment: You can check the position of a character in a string with the [String.IndexOf Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and one of the overloads lets you start at a specified position. Remember that the first character is at position 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can count the number of the occurences of a character with the LINQ extension method `Count` applied to a string, because a string is considered as being an enumeration of characters.

If VB does not know `Count`, add an `Imports System.Linq` to your code.

```
Dim theChar As Char = "x"C
Dim count As Integer = FirstName.Count(Function(c) c = theChar)
If count > 1 Then
    FirstName = FirstName.Replace(theChar, "_"C)
End If
```

You can replace the character easily with the string method `Replace`.

You can write character constants by appending a "C" to a one character string.

```
Dim aCharacter As Char = "x"C
Dim aString As String = "x"
```

But if you are not used to LINQ you can of course use a good old loop for counting a character

```
Dim count As Integer = 0
For i As Integer = 0 To FirstName.Length - 1
    If FirstName(i) = theChar Then
        count += 1
    End If
Next i
```